# Launching a bash shell from a sudo-ed environment

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Apologies for the confusing Question title. I am trying to launch an interactive bash shell from a shell script ( say shel2.sh) which has been launched by a parent script (shel1.sh) in a sudo-ed environment. ( I am creating a guided deployment 
script for my software which needs to be installed as super-user , hence the sudo, but may need the user to access the shell. )

Here's shel1.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
sudo bash << EOF
echo $?
./shel2.sh
EOF
echo shel1 done
```

And here's shel2.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
bash --norc --verbose --noprofile -i
echo $?    
echo done
```

I expected this to launch an interactive bash shell which waits for my input before returning to shel1.sh. This is what I see:

```
+ ./shel1.sh
+ sudo bash
0
+ bash --norc --verbose --noprofile -i
bash-4.3# exit
+ echo 0
0
+ echo done
done
+ echo shel1 done
shel1 done
```

The bash-4.3# calls an exit automatically and quits. Interestingly if I invoke the bash shell with -l (or --login) the automatic entry is **logout** !

Can someone explain what is happening here ?

Comment: It probably doesn't have access to the terminal.  `bash -i </dev/null` is sufficient to repro.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'doesn't have access'  ? Can I 'enable' the access somehow  ?

Comment: Whe you use a here document (like `<<EOF`) you are redirecting stdin. Depends on how you run the script, too; a `cron` job will obviously never have access to an interactive terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a here document, you are tying up the shell's -- and its spawned child processes' -- standard input to the here document input.

You can avoid using a here document in many situations.  For example, replace the here document with a single-quoted string.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
sudo bash -c '
    # Aside: How is this actually useful?
    echo $?
    # Spawned script inherits the stdin of "sudo bash"
    ./shel2.sh'
echo shel1 done
```

Without more details, it's hard to see where exactly you want to go with this, but most modern Linux platforms have package managers which allow all kinds of hooks for installation, so that you would typically not need to do this sort of thing.  Have you looked into that?

Comment: Your example here document was unquoted, so the *calling* shell would expand the value of `$?` in the here document before passing it to the new Bash instance. I assume that was a mistake; if not, try double quotes instead of single around the embedded script.